# How to access a collection within a collection in Firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to access the document data from bank_account_2, and the problem is that bank_account_2 that is a collection within a collection. Basically we have users>user1>bank_accounts>bank_account_2

But I didn't find a way to do this using the modular version 9 for websites. This is my code for now, does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance!

```
//----Getting the user data------
import { doc, collection, getDocs, getDoc} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-firestore.js";
import db from "./database.js"


const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [`doc`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#collection), you can use a "slash-separated path to a collection" as follows:

```
await getDocs(collection(db, "users/user1/bank_accounts"));
```

Of course you want the ID of the user doc to be variable. So you can either do:

```
const userId = "user1";
await getDocs(collection(db, "users/" + userId + "/bank_accounts"));
```

or, by using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals);

```
const userId = "user1";
await getDocs(collection(db, `users/${userId}/bank_accounts`));
```

*(Note that template literals are enclosed by backtick (`) characters instead of double or single quotes)*

---

But you could also pass the different sub-collection path segments to the `collection()` method, like:

```
const userId = "user1";
await getDocs(collection(db, "users", userId, "bank_accounts"));
```

---

Moreover... you could even mix the two above approaches, as follows!

```
const userId = "user1";
await getDocs(collection(db, `users/${userId}`, "bank_accounts"));
```

or

```
const userId = "user1";
await getDocs(collection(db, "users", `${userId}/bank_accounts`));
```

Comment: Hey @LaraCalvo, did you have the opportunity to look at the answer?